# How to draw a triangle at the position which the user clicks on

Tags: java, swing, graphics, drawing

I'm trying to draw a triangle at the position which the user clicks on.

This is what I've done so far:

```
int[] xPoints = {(xPosition / 2), xPosition, (xPosition + (xPosition / 2))};
int[] yPoints = {(yPosition + yPosition), yPosition, (yPosition + yPosition)};
g.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, 3);
```

The problem is that the size of the triangle varies depending on the xPosition and yPosition (these are taken from mouse coordinates).

Any ideas how I can just place a fixed size triangle at the specified X and Y coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `xPosition / 2` and `yPosition` for the first and third points, use a fixed offset from the `xPosition` like so:

```
//use whatever size you want
//this will make a triangle with the top at the clicked point
int halfWidth = 50, height = 100; 
int[] xPoints = { xPosition - halfWidth, xPosition, xPosition + halfWidth };
int[] yPoints = { yPosition + height, yPosition, yPosition + height };
```

You can play around with the sizes, but if you want it to be equilateral, then `height` should  be `Math.sqrt(3) * halfWidth`.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a size and call it SIZE:

```
int[] xPoints = {xPosition, xPosition, xPosition + SIZE))};
int[] yPoints = {yPosition, yPosition + SIZE, yPosition))};
```

This will draw a triangle which doesn't change size at different points. However, if you want a certain kind of triangle which points a certain direction, you will need to use some geometry and perhaps trigonometry to do the calculations.

Comment: @DotNET You're right. The points in my original answer were all in a straight line. This edited version should make a triangle.